# Azure Data Factory - Order of actions inside the Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a tricky question about the "Copy Activity" in ADF. Assume the following scenario:

1. Source: an external API or an non-Azure database using hosted integration runtime.
2. Sink: an Azure SQL Server database.
3. The "pre-copy Script" field has a command to delete some data from the sink table (why deleting is out of scope of the discussion).

When the pipeline runs, the connection with the source fails (due to a time-out, network issue, authentication, etc.)

The question is: will the pre-copy script run in this case? Or the script only runs after ADF successfully connected the source data store? I couldn't find any reference about it.

I can just try to simulate it and see what happens, but I'm hopping someone can save my time. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pre-copy script won't run. As I understand, we can consider it as a workflow, connect to source--> get data from source-->connect to sink-->run the pre-copy script-->write data to sink. No mater which step failed, data factory will stop run.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience about Data Factory, the pre-copy script won't run.

As I understand, we can consider it as a workflow, connect to source--> get data from source-->connect to sink-->run the pre-copy script-->write data to sink. No mater which step failed, data factory will stop run.

Comment: Although I haven't confirmed it myself, I will accept as correct answer, as it makes completely sense for me. Thanks!